# How do SOCs transmit at a higher speed than the internal clock?

Tags: microcontroller, rf, frequency

E.g. ESP 32 has an internal clock of 240MHz, but can transmit at 2.4GHz (following 802.11 standard). 
How is this accomplished? Does it really generates a wave at 2.4GHz frequency? Is it not limited by the internal clock?
I know it's digital modulation and I'm still learning about RF so any recomended literature would also be appreciated.

Comment: 240MHz isn't the internal clock so much as the clock the processor is fed and runs at

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew that.

Comment: Yes, most systems have multiple internal clocks.

Answer (score 1):

Modulation is not typically done at the carrier frequency, but rather at a lower frequency and upconverted.  In the era of digital modulation, it's not even uncommon for the key processing to be done in the context if IQ signals centered on a frequency if 0 Hz.

Upconversion does require a local oscillator, but this is a sine wave rather than square, and only drives a small part of the radio circuitry, not the chip in general.  Typically today that would be synthesized in relation to a convenient frequency crystal.

Comment: Thanks! This helps me a lot. Have a nice one.